# range.find: find next match in an excel table, using office-js

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I'm trying to create a small Excel script lab example that finds all matches of a search string within a selected range.
However, unlike VBA, the range.find() method does not appear to have a way to find the next match?

Answer (score 0):

A new range instance is returned from the call to the `find` method. Going to the next cell you could start anew with a new range.

Comment: Yes I know. So what if I want to search within a range? So suppose I want to limit my search to B2:D10 and find all entries in that range?